FEA: ANSYS conversion issue after warning
My Ansys model can't converge and giving me this warnings and those two errors below before failing the analysis
Warning: [orange] Solver pivot warnings or errors have been encountered during the solution.  This is usually a result of an ill conditioned matrix possibly due to unreasonable material properties, an under constrained model, or contact related issues.  Check results carefully.
Warning: [yellow] During this solution, the elapsed time exceeded the CPU time by an excessive margin.  Often this indicates either a lack of physical memory (RAM) required to efficiently handle this simulation or it indicates a particularly slow hard drive configuration.  This simulation can be expected to run faster on identical hardware if additional RAM or a faster hard drive configuration is made available.  For more details, please see the Ansys Performance Guide which is part of the Ansys Help system.
Error: An internal solution magnitude limit was exceeded. (Node Number 258120, Body 3022-0010.asm|3022-0012.prt|3022-00122, DOF UY) Please check your Environment for inappropriate load values or insufficient supports.  You may select the offending object and/or geometry via RMB on this warning in the Messages window.  Please see the Troubleshooting section of the Help System for more information.
Error: The solver engine was unable to converge on a solution for the nonlinear problem as constrained.  Please see the Troubleshooting section of the Help System for more information.
The picture below is at the end of the run.



What is the question? More specific information about the problem you are solving will probably be required. What you can based on these errors is to identify the node due to which the solution magnitude was exceeded. You can select it using Named selection, defined by Worksheet and add the node based on its id number. At least you will get to know which part of the model is causing the error.

I am new to Ansys and self learner. How can I do name selection? Which you call Worksheet?

https://innovationspace.ansys.com/courses/courses/high-resolution-fe-model-of-bone/lessons/physics-setup-lesson-5-14/topic/3-named-selection/
